# Alert disapproved products script in Google Ads

Tags: google-ads-api

I have a Google Ads Script, which is supposed to notify me via e-mail, when products in my merchant center account are disapproved.

There is a "include" filter field in this script, which limits the monitored products, however, I can't get it to work. Everything else seems to be working.

This is the part of the script, where you can filter the products:

```
var productIdToInclude = [];
```

I have tried the following versions, to no avail:

```
var productIdToInclude = ["product123"];
var productIdToInclude = ['product123'];
var productIdToInclude = [product123];
```

This is the comment in the script about this filter:

```
// Filters
// These two variables store the product ID's that we want to filter by.
// The ID's need to be in string format e.g. productIdToInclude = ["123"];
```

The whole script can be found [here](https://github.com/Brainlabs-Digital/Google-Ads-Scripts/blob/master/Monitoring/gmc-disapproval-checker.js).

I believe, that I have a synthax error, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: The code comment in the script says:`
    // Filters
    // These two variables store the product ID's that we want to filter by.
    // The ID's need to be in string format e.g. productIdToInclude = ["123"];
    // These are actually substrings of the productId so be careful not to use
    // strings which are not reasonably specific.`

Are you sure your product ID is correct?

Comment: Yes, the product ID is correct for sure.

Comment: What do you mean by 'no avail'? Do you want to get info for only "product123" OR do you want to skip this product and get rest of them?

Comment: Both would work for me, optimally I would like to include several products and run the script only for them. I have tried both excluding and including single product IDs, as well as a series of IDs.

Comment: @user1721135 I have added my suggestion as an answer but not sure if that will work to be honest, let me know how it works, apart from that everything seems normal. I wasn't able to find `approvalStatus` property on the product status object for v2.1 so not sure if you are using v2 of api or if that is something you should look in to as well. https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/reference/rest/v2.1/productstatuses#productstatusdestinationstatus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter logic in the script seems to be working fine for include but for exclude I did found some issue. Update your exclude function and see if that works.

```js
function satisfiesIdExcludeFilters(productIdToExclude, product) {
  if (productIdToExclude.length) {
    for (index = 0; index < productIdToExclude.length; ++index) {
      if (product['productId'].indexOf(productIdToExclude[index]) !== -1) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Updated script should look like:

```js
/**
 *
 * GMC Disapproval Checker
 *
 * This script checks your Google Merchant Centre for disapproved products. It will send you emails if the percentage of
 * disapproved products exceeds a specified threshold. You need to select the Shopping Content api in the Advanced Apis
 * section to run this script.
 *
 * Google AdWords Script maintained on brainlabsdigital.com
 *
 */


// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
// Options

var merchantId = '';
// Replace this with your Merchant Center ID.

var threshold = 30;
// Percentage of disapproved products you would like to be alerted by.
// Do NOT include the percentage sign in this variable.

var email = ['aa@example.com'];
// Email addresses to send the disapproval alert to.
// If there is more than one email they should be comma separated
// - e.g. ["aa@example.com", "bb@example.com"]

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
// Filters
// These two variables store the product ID's that we want to filter by.
// The ID's need to be in string format e.g. productIdToInclude = ["123"];
// These are actually substrings of the productId so be careful not to use
// strings which are not reasonably specific.

var productIdToInclude = ['Z200'];
var productIdToExclude = [];

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
// Functions

function main() {

  var pageToken;
  var maxResults = 250;
  // These variables are used to fetch all the products (maximum of 250) on a page
  // in the merchant centre. We can then iterate over the pages by using the next
  // page token which is given as part of the response to our request.

  var totalProducts = 0;
  var disapprovedProducts = [];

  do {
    // This is a quick check to see if the filters supplied are valid
    checkFiltersDontContradict(productIdToInclude, productIdToExclude);

    var productStatuses = ShoppingContent.Productstatuses.list(merchantId, {
      pageToken: pageToken,
      maxResults: maxResults
    });

    // If the 'approvalStatus' of our product is not 'approved' then we say it is disapproved.
    if (productStatuses.resources) {
      for (var i = 0; i < productStatuses.resources.length; i++) {
        product = productStatuses.resources[i];
        if (satisfiesAllFilters(product)) {
          totalProducts += 1;
          if (product['destinationStatuses'][0]['approvalStatus'] == 'disapproved') {
            disapprovedProducts.push(product['productId']);
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No more products in account ' + merchantId);
    }
    // We then pull our next PageToken from our response and use it to make a new request.
    // If there is no next PageToken then we exit our iteration.
    pageToken = productStatuses.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);

  disapprovalPercentage = (disapprovedProducts.length * 100) / totalProducts;
  Logger.log(disapprovedProducts.length + ' of ' + totalProducts +
    ' products in your account were disapproved - ' +
    disapprovalPercentage.toFixed(2) + '%')

  // If our threshold is exceeded then we assemble an email with details of the alert and send it to our contact emails.
  if (disapprovalPercentage >= threshold) {

    var subject = merchantId + ' GMC Disapproval Alert Email';
    var message = disapprovedProducts.length + ' of ' + totalProducts +
      ' products in your GMC (' + merchantId + ') were disapproved - ' +
      disapprovalPercentage.toFixed(2) + '%' + '\n' +
      'Disapproved products: ' + disapprovedProducts.join('\n');

    MailApp.sendEmail(email.join(','), subject, message);
    Logger.log('Message to ' + email.join(',') + ' sent.');
  }
}

function checkFiltersDontContradict(productIdToInclude, productIdToExclude) {
  if (productIdToInclude.length && productIdToExclude.length) {
    for (var i in productIdToInclude) {
      if (productIdToExclude.indexOf(productIdToInclude[i]) > -1) {
        throw "Filters have shared values - can not include and exclude simultaneously";
      }
    }
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function satisfiesAllFilters(product) {
  return (satisfiesIdIncludeFilters(productIdToInclude, product) &&
    satisfiesIdExcludeFilters(productIdToExclude, product));
}

function satisfiesIdIncludeFilters(productIdToInclude, product) {
  if (productIdToInclude.length) {
    for (index = 0; index < productIdToInclude.length; ++index) {
      if (product['productId'].indexOf(productIdToInclude[index]) !== -1) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function satisfiesIdExcludeFilters(productIdToExclude, product) {
  if (productIdToExclude.length) {
    for (index = 0; index < productIdToExclude.length; ++index) {
      if (product['productId'].indexOf(productIdToExclude[index]) !== -1) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is a real ID for example: Z200. Still doesn't work unfortunately, returns 0 out of 0 when including a disapproved product.

Comment: @user1721135 Is it possible for you to post one of the productStatus that way it will be easier to debug the script and check.

Comment: Status of a product is either "Disapproved or invalid" or "Active"

Comment: I would also be happy, if I could have the IDs in the mail, and have another loop to parse for hardcoded ID for example

Comment: Amazing. Seems to be working, will test more and award, thank you.

Comment: @user1721135 I was unit testing few things and did found issue in exclude function, checkout my updated script. I also included product ids in the email.

Comment: @user1721135 any luck?